# Is there a way to call a function when the user returns to the previous page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

So I'm creating a website using Ruby on rails and I have a timer on a page.
The timer goes from 5 to 0 and then a game starts. However, if you return to the previous page before the timer ends and then start the timer again, both timer will exist and the timer will go down twice as fast.

So I need to destroy my timer when returning to the previous page, but using the unload event doesn't work because the page doesn't unload when returning to the previous page. Is there a "onreturn" event or something similar that I could use ?

Here is my timer :

```
var timeleft = 6;
var gameTimer = setInterval(function(){
    timeleft--;
    afficherChaine("Le jeu va commencer dans " + timeleft + " secondes !"); //afficherChaine just prints something for the user 
    if(timeleft <= 0){
        clearInterval(gameTimer);
        jouer();
    }
},1000);
```

I tried that but it does not work :

```
window.onpopstate = function(event){
    clearInterval(gameTimer);
}
```

EDIT : I've tried to do `gameTimerID = null;` just in case but it does not change anything. Looks like the timer just wont dissapear. Am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan Yes, because my timer is in javascript

Comment: hope you are using turbolinks.You can refresh the timer when turbolink:load and start the timer again

Comment: ```window.onpopstate = function(event){
    console.log(gameTimer);
    clearInterval(gameTimer);
}
```
what is output?

Comment: @KostyaTresko I get a number that increases with time

Comment: So now problem is that you cannot clear interval and not that you cannot capture the event? If it so It would be nice if you will provide jsfiddle reproducing this problem and event for clearing interval can be for example button click

Answer (score 0):

Try `onpopstate`. As stated `A popstate event is dispatched to the window each time the active history entry changes between two history entries for the same document`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

Comment: I don't really know why but it does not work. I'll add some code to my post

Answer (score 0):

Rail user turbolinks to load pages.
I recommend to use `jquery-rails`
try using

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:before-cache", function() {
 clearInterval(gameTimer);
});
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you said, but I edited my post, and it looks like the problem is the clearInterval